# The getter " type" was called on null. error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I have a function like this,

```
  changingTheSubjectOptions() {
    if (registerType.type == "Teacher") {
      subjectsOptionShow = true;
    } else {
      subjectsOptionShow = false;
    }
    return subjectsOptionShow;
  }
```

Here the value of `registerType.type` is changing when the user selects the dropdown option here,

```
  RegisterType registerType;
  List<RegisterType> registrationList = <RegisterType>[
    RegisterType(type: "Student"),
    RegisterType(type: "Teacher"),
  ];

DropdownButton<RegisterType>(
                    value: registerType,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    iconSize: 24,
                    elevation: 16,
                    hint: Container(
                      // width: 200,
                      child: Text("You are ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: 15)),
                    ),
                    underline: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    onChanged: (RegisterType newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        registerType = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: registrationList
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<RegisterType>>(
                            (RegisterType value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<RegisterType>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value.type),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
```

Now when I call the function like this,

```
Visibility(
                visible: changingTheSubjectOptions(),
```

it gives an error, 
**The getter 'type' was called on null.**
Upto here I understand that `registerType.type`  is null. 
But also after I initialize the `registerType.type`  in initState, it gives the same error.

```
  void initState() {
    registerType.type = "Student";
    super.initState();
  }
```

**How can I initialize it?**

Comment: Can you post RegisterType code?

Answer (score 0):

`registerType` is null, not `registerType.type`. Maybe initialize it to something or use it with null checks.

Probably this will get rid of your error:

```
    if (registerType?.type == "Teacher") {
```

Comment: I could not understand you well, can you please help me by updating the code.
I only want to get the dropdown value and change the boolean according to it.